# Cannot Figure out What is Causing Extra Spacing at the top of site

Tags: html, css, wordpress, spacing

I have been combing through the code on this site and I cannot figure out what is causing the extra spacing that is showing at the very top of the site.  There is a little 10px white space before the beige bar on the top and I need to get rid of it.  On the home page it is not there.

The url is: [Broken spacing](http://www.scalingbackblog.com/savory-bites/butternut-squash-noodles-with-creamy-miso-tahini-sauce/)

I have inspected this thing up and down and even did a side by side file comparison and cannot figure out what is causing this.  Any pointers would be great.

Comment: Adding you code snippet is a good way to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ABG Rich Pins extension is adding `<div>` tags inside the `<head>` which is invalid markup with undefined behaviour.

```
<head>
...
<div class="abg_rp_movie_div">
<!-- ABG Rich Pins by Antonio Borrero Granell 1.1 -->
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Scaling Back">
<div itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Movie">
<meta itemprop="url" content="http://www.scalingbackblog.com/savory-bites/butternut-squash-noodles-with-creamy-miso-tahini-sauce/">
<h1 itemprop="name"></h1>
<span itemprop="description"></span>
<div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
<span itemprop="ratingValue"></span>
<span itemprop="bestRating"></span>
</div>
<meta itemprop="datePublished" content="">
<meta itemprop="contentRating" content="G">
</div>
<!-- /ABG Rich Pins -->
</div>
...
</head>
```

This is where the spacing is coming from.

Comment: Thanks @pjumble that was it!  I just added a margin-top:-10px and it took care of it.

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you how to take that out, but there are probably someone out there who have the time to look at your stylesheets.. but here's what you can do. Somewhere in your stylesheet add this:

```
CSS:

body {
    position: relative;
    top: -10px;
}
```